# How to add scopes using expo's example on Google Authentication + firebase

Tags: react-native, expo, google-oauth

I'm creating an app using react native + expo + firebase + google apis.

I'm trying to use certain Google products (lets say, calendar)

I'm trying to grab user's access token from Google

Expo has this document

https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#google

Unfortunately, their document is not complete, there's no other guides or API documentations. (They don't even document some functions that they are using)

There's no instructions on how to add scopes when following this method.

Has anyone succeeded in attaching a scope and grabbing a valid access token?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks